# underline cont

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, text

This is a continuation of the question below.

Basically I discovered its no problem at all to draw lines or shapes or whatever directly onto an mx:Text object using its graphics property  (Text.graphics.lineTo, etc.).  If just displaying that text,  then any such drawn lines are displayed as well.  However, if that Text object is used as a mask,  then any  drawn lines on that text object are merely ignored when the mask is rendered.

And its hard for me to see the reason behind this, if anyone else is able to.  I mean you're designating the Text object itself as the mask.  It seems like any visual change to that text object should be part of the mask.

Comment: Which question was that?  Your OP title isn't very meaningful either.

Comment: "underline line thickness always one pixel…" was the original post. So basically, I'm doing underlines manually to get the thickness I want.

Comment: you really should edit and update your original question instead of posting a new one - question order is not guaranteed, so this won't make much sense to people.

Answer (score 1):

The graphics.lineTo method doesn't appear to create a mask regardless of where it is called.

However, calling

```
 txt1.graphics.beginFill(0);
 txt1.graphics.drawRect(...)  //(where the Rectangle is thin enough to be a line)
 txt1.graphics.endFill();
```

does in fact work as a mask,  (adding the shape to the actual text which then collectively form a mask).  (But the coordinates of the rectangle are scaled by whatever txt1.scaleX,scaleY is currently so that has to be considered as well.)